# Eazfusctor.net - Excluding Files

Tags: .net, obfuscation, eazfuscator

I am using Eazfuscator.NET to obfuscate my project.

I sifted through the documentation of Eazfuscator (perhaps not in-depth enough) and was wondering how to exclude specific .cs files of my project from obfuscation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer after reading more in-depth into the documentation, haha:

Here is for future reference if anyone else is looking into it:

```
[System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(Feature = "renaming", ApplyToMembers = true)]
```

^This is for disabling class and its members renaming only.

Comment: Hi Kevin, any idea how can I set it for Windows store class library? As System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute not there in Windows store.

Comment: @Tarak - Just add a source file _"C:\Program Files\(x86)\Eazfuscator.NET\Code Snippets\C#\ObfuscationAttributes.cs"_ to your project. After that you can use `ObfuscationAttribute` the same way as a built-in attribute.